# Pytest: pytest.ini file in subdirectories

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest

Let's consider my current directory is `/folder`.

There is `pytest.ini` file in `/folder/sub/`.

There is a `test_file.py`  and '`test_file1.py` inside `/folder/sub/.../tests/`.

Now If I try to run `pytest /folder/sub/.../tests/test_file.py`, my `/folder/sub/pytest.ini` is considered, but if I try to run all the tests just running `pytest` then `/folder/sub/pytest.ini` is not considered.

Is there any explanation or Am I missing something?

if there is pytest.ini in any sub folders will it be considered when running tests from outside?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, `pytest.ini` is a global one, would be read once on start depending on the working folder. Don't rely on configuration per folder, use fixtures or other techniques instead.